# Upcasting in Java for non primitive types

Tags: java, casting

Let us consider we have two classes A and B. B is a sub class for A because B extends A. If We create an instance of A Class and assign that in to a A type will contains all the properties of A. Similarly when I create an Instance of B and assign it to B type will get all the properties of B along with properties of A because it is inheriting from A. According to above lines instance of A contains properties a few as compared to properties contains to instance B. That means Instance of B is Bigger than Instance of A as casting should be explicit when narrowing implicit when widening. According to my theory Instance of B is bigger we are trying to store it in A type we need conversion.

```
A a1=new (A)B();
```

The above conversion is taking place implicitly. But my question is how it is implicit, Instance of B is bigger we are trying to convert that to small type which is A. How this is possible???

Answer me with examples thank you in advance.

Comment: A bit of **"try it out"** code would be useful.

Comment: Thinking of types as "bigger" or "smaller" is a problem by itself.  All references are the same size.

Comment: casting does not mean converting, you're not "shrinking" object B to object A, you just say that variable a1 is "at least A", as soon as every B is always "at least A", you don't need to do explicit casting

Comment: Something needs to point out: `A a1=new (A)B();` is explicit casting, NOT implicit

Comment: @Jason: actually `new (A)B();` isn't casting, it's just a compile error.

Comment: @user3437460 I could imagine such construction in c++ language with casting operation overloaded, not in java

Comment: @AslanBasha Take a look at my solution below and let me know whether it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking in terms of object size, but in Java, non primitive types are never contained, only referred to. Thus, your code is casting the result of `new B()`, which is of type "reference to B", to type " reference to A". Since all references are the same size, no data is lost in the cast.

Answer (score 0):

The cast isn't actually implicit like you're saying. What is actually happening is this:

```
B b1 = new B();
A a1 = (A)b;
```

The `(A)` is an **explicit** cast, what's more important is to stop considering the *size* of things in the sense that the *size* of `B` is different from the *size* of `A`. This can be an implicit assignment because `B` IS-A `A`, so using `A` as an interface for `B` is completely safe, because we know that `B` has **at least** the same members as defined by `A`.

So the perfectly safe (and not erroneous) method of doing this is simple:

```
A a1 = new B();
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

So, I really don't understand your question. I just think you are confused about what happens to the class B members when a upcast to his super class is made. In that case, you ended up with a instance of A wich means that Object type is A and non of B stored data will remain.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, with

```
B b = new B();
A a = b;
```

one defines *references* `b` and `a`. Under the hood, references are implemented with pointers, and thus, all references are the same size. Of course, an instance of a `B` might indeed require more memory than an instance of `A` (I take it, this is what you mean by "bigger").

By the way, in C++ this is not the case.

```
B b();
```

does define an object, not a reference, and therefore

```
A a = b;
```

in C++ is indeed *not* allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this:

```
class Animal{
    public void eat(){}
}

class Monkey extends Animal{
    public void climbTree(){}
}
```

I can now do this:

```
Animal someAnimal = new Monkey();  //This is ok. (Create a Monkey and identify is as an Animal)
someAnimal.eat();                  //This is ok too. (All Animal objects can eat)
someAnimal.climbTree();            //Not ok. Java sees someAnimal as a general Animal, not a Monkey yet.
```

From the above example, someAnimal is a `Monkey` object which is stored within a variable of higher hierarchy (`Animal`).
The object itself is perceived as the a more general class (The `Animal` class) and I don't think an implicit casting is done here since all Monkeys are already Animals (but not the other way round).

Explicit casting can be done when you want to let the compiler knows that the object actually belongs to a more specific class. For example:

```
((Monkey)someAnimal).climbTree();  //This is ok. Inform Java someAnimal is actually a Monkey which knows how to climb.
```

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
Class Employee {

    private String name;
    private double Salary;

//getter & setter

//mutators to increase salary etc;
}

class Manager extends Employee {

    private double bonus;

//inherits methods from superclass

// sub class specific methods

}

Employee e = new Manager(); //is fine as manager is also an Employee...
```

The prefixes super and sub come from the language of sets used in theoretical computer science and mathematics. The set of all employees contains the set of all managers, and thus is said to be a superset of the set of managers. Or, to put it another way, the set of all managers is a subset of the set of all employees.

~ From core java series
hope this helps...